# How to resolve dependencies swinject (without storyboard), where is another important controller taken as rootVC?

Tags: ios, swift, swinject

I dont have storyboard in my app. So all my dependencies spelled out in App Delegate. I read the documentation of the Swinject and there the option is suggested:

> window.rootViewController =
>   container.resolve(PersonViewController.self)

But in my case, the root controller is the tab bar controller (`MainTabBarController()`), which sets the layout of my collections view and other options. How can this be fixed?

Initially, I tried to do everything through the Swinject Storyboard, but storyboardInitCompleted() just dont worked for me and my `viewModel: ViewModelProtocol!` remained `nil` (Resolution failed in console).

App Delegate:

```
 @UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?
  let container: Container = {
    let container = Container()
    container.register(UnsplashService.self){ _ in UnsplashService()}//.inObjectScope(.container)
    container.register(UnsplashManagerProtocol.self){ r in UnsplashDataFetcher(with: r.resolve(UnsplashService.self)!)}//.inObjectScope(.container)
    container.register(ViewModelProtocol.self){ r in ViewModel(withClient: r.resolve(UnsplashManagerProtocol.self)!)}//.inObjectScope(.container)
    container.register(PhotosCollectionViewController.self) { r in
      let controller = PhotosCollectionViewController()
      controller.viewModel = r.resolve(ViewModelProtocol.self)
      return controller
    }
    return container
  }()

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let homeVC = UIViewController()
    homeVC.view.backgroundColor = .white
    window!.rootViewController = MainTabBarController()
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    //window.rootViewController = container.resolve(PhotosCollectionViewController.self)

    return true
  }
```

MainTabBarController:

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

  var photosVC: PhotosCollectionViewController!
  var likesVC: LikesCollectionViewController!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     //view.backgroundColor = .white
   }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    photosVC = PhotosCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: WaterfallLayout())

    likesVC = LikesCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    viewControllers = [
      generateNavigationController(rootViewController: photosVC, title: "Photos", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "photos")),
      generateNavigationController(rootViewController: likesVC, title: "Favourites", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart"))
    ]
  }

  private func generateNavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController, title: String, image: UIImage) -> UIViewController {
    let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    navigationVC.tabBarItem.title = title
    navigationVC.tabBarItem.image = image
    return navigationVC
  }
}
```

PhotosCollectionViewController:

```
class PhotosCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

  var viewModel: ViewModelProtocol!

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should register your `MainTabBarController`

```
container.register(MainTabBarController.self) { r in
   let controller = MainTabBarController()
   conteroller.photosVC: r.resolve(PhotosCollectionViewController.self)!
   conteroller.likesVC: r.resolve(LikesCollectionViewController.self)!)
   return controller
}
```

and resolve it with

```
window!.rootViewController = container.resolve(MainTabBarController.self)!
```